# Receive params in jax-rs post method

Tags: java, post, curl, jax-rs

I know ques about jaxrs params has been asked multiple times and have very good explanation of most things.But I could not find answer to a very simple question. **How can i receive params in post request?**

My Jax-RS method

```
@POST
    @Path("data")
    //@Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    String getMobileServiceRepresentation(@PathParam("username") String username,@PathParam("password") String password) {
        println  username+":"+password 
        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject('{"dashboards": ["Dashbaord1","Dashboard2"]}')
        obj
    }
```

It prints `null:null`

My request is via curl ie

```
curl -X POST --data "username=username&password=pass" http://localhost:8080/blablaApp/api/mobileService/data
```

Also I have already used `@Context UriInfo abc` to get all context params. But no luck found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use the `@FormParam` annotation instead of the `@PathParam` one on the method arguments. `@PathParam` is used when you want to retrieve parts of the request URI. In your case, you want to retrieve request body content.

Comment: and from param is used when a Form is submitted with in-form params.

Thanks for taking interest anyways.

Comment: It also works (at least on my machine) with the curl command example you showed. Did you try it ?

Comment: Yeah Working fine! stupid me, sorry for condescending behavior. Thanks

Comment: No problem, thanks for confirming it works for you, and glad I could help you ;-)